# Why would `mysqli_fetch_assoc` be returning an empty object?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having to debug some legacy PHP code and I've hit a real puzzler.

A method loops through each row of a MySQL table and adds the row to an array.

Unfortunately, the method is returning a completely empty object, so the HTTP response is of zero-length.

It seems that one particular row in the MySQL table is causing this issue, when `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is called.  I've narrowed it down to row 1251 by adding in the test code below.

```
$counter = 0
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findInfo) ) {

  // My Debug Test Code: bail out and return row 1251
  if ($counter ==   1251)
     return $row; // this returns a populated array for all rows except 1251, which is blank

  // Add the row to our array
  array_push($rowArray, $row);

  $counter = $counter + 1
}

// Finally, do something with all the rows
return $rowArray
```

If I generate a .CSV dump of the data table, the data looks fairly innocuous - row 1251 is the line beginning `94340` in the snippet below:

```
94339,"Hills Coaches (Wolverhampton)",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
94340,"Hinckley Bus",,"via contact form at www.arrivabus.co.uk/contact-arriva/  ","01455 239329",,,"5 Jacknell Road, Dodwells Bridge Industrial Estate, Hinckley LE10 3BS",,,,,,,,,,www.arrivabus.co.uk/hinckleybus/#http://www.arrivabus.co.uk/hinckleybus/#
94341,Hirethisbus.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

What might cause `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to apparently 'bail out' in this way and return nothing?   How would I even debug this?

Comment: What exactly is there in `$row` on that record?

Comment: It may be unrelated, but your line `94340` looks like it misses some double quotes somewhere. Still, can you `print_r($row)` for `1251` and post the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL row contained some unprintable characters, determined by connecting to the server via the `MySQL` client and running a manual `SELECT` on the row.

```
`SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE Id = SomeID`

======+==========+===========
ColumnName +========+========
=============================
http://some.site.com/??
=============================
```

The two question marks were the giveaway.

Still no idea why `mysqli_fetch_assoc` was unhappy with it, though.